# create Button instance throws NullPointerException in AnimatorSet.clone

Tags: android

I have an issue creating a Button programmatically. The button is supposed to be inserted in a pre-existing layout.

And since I need the dimensions of a specific container I created a global layout listener for that container and in the onGlobalLayout callback i check for a valid size and then instantiate a new Button.

The context used is the context from the container.

```
final View container = activity.findViewById(...);
container.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (container.getWidth()>0 && container.getHeight()>0) {
            Button button = new Button(container.getContext());
        }
    }
});
```

However, in rare cases - specifically when switching from one activity to another - the Button instanciation fails with a NullPointerException in the Android framework code.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.animation.Animator android.animation.AnimatorSet$Node.mAnimation' on a null object reference
at android.animation.AnimatorSet.clone(AnimatorSet.java:725)
at android.animation.AnimatorSet.clone(AnimatorSet.java:682)
at android.animation.StateListAnimator.clone(StateListAnimator.java:148)
at android.animation.StateListAnimator$StateListAnimatorConstantState.newInstance(StateListAnimator.java:328)
at android.animation.StateListAnimator$StateListAnimatorConstantState.newInstance(StateListAnimator.java:327)
at android.content.res.ConstantState.newInstance(ConstantState.java:53)
at android.content.res.ConstantState.newInstance(ConstantState.java:61)
at android.content.res.ConfigurationBoundResourceCache.getInstance(ConfigurationBoundResourceCache.java:40)
at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:163)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4815)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:995)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:113)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:106)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:102)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:98)
```

My assumption is that somehow the Context ist not valid any more but I can't put my finger on it..

I do remove the listener when the activity gets deactivated.

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you remove the listener?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @CoXier the code above is just a simplification. In actual fact the class holding the code implements the OnGlobalLayoutListener interface and the instance is later removed again (using the usual sdk level check and do removeGlobalOnLayoutListener or removeOnGlobalLayoutListener, repect.)

Comment: Are you unregistering listener in `onDestroy()`?

Comment: @StanislavBondar yes

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem ?

Comment: @Abhi yes, I posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found so far is to not create the button by calling

```
Button button = new Button(container.getContext());
```

but by creating a small layout xml file only containing the button and then instantiate the button like so:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.button, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

As docs says [OnGlobalLayoutListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html)

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes.

So when UI is destroing, you are getting "dying" `View` that causes NPE. You can try to unregister listener in `onStop()` to prevent that. Or if you need just to handle fully created `View` use

```
container.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Button button = new Button(container.getContext());
        }
    });
```

Comment: a posted Runnable may be called on the UI thread and when the container is actually created, but it seems layouting must not necessarily be complete; i usually get the callbacks when getWidth() and getHeight() still return 0.